# Decrypting AES cipher text

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

Consider the following test:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestAes256EcbPkcs7Stream()
    {
        // 504 bytes of plain text
        const string inputString = new string('z', 504);
        var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
        byte[] key = {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        };
        var rij = new RijndaelManaged
        {
            BlockSize = 256, // 256 bits == 32 bytes
            Key = key,
            IV = key, // just for test
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        };
        var enc = rij.CreateEncryptor();
        var encBytes = enc.TransformFinalBlock(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(512, encBytes.Length);
        var dec = rij.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] decBytes = new byte[inputBytes.Length];
        int decPos = 0;
        using (var cipherMs = new MemoryStream(encBytes))
        {
            var buf = new byte[32];
            // process all blocks except the last one
            while (cipherMs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)==buf.Length &&
                cipherMs.Length!=cipherMs.Position)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w!=buf.Length;)
                {
                    w += dec.TransformBlock(buf, 0, buf.Length, decBytes, decPos);
                    decPos += w;
                }
            }
            // ensure that we read all blocks
            Assert.IsTrue(cipherMs.Length==cipherMs.Position);
            // process the last block
            var tailBytes = dec.TransformFinalBlock(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            // here decPos==480, that means 480 bytes were written to decBytes
            // and 504-480 = 24 bytes come from TransformFinalBlock
            Assert.AreEqual(24, tailBytes.Length); // <- fail, because the actual length is 56
            Buffer.BlockCopy(tailBytes, 0, decBytes, decPos, tailBytes.Length);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(inputBytes, decBytes);
    }
```

For some reason I got 56-byte final block instead of 24-byte.
I suppose, `TransformBlock`/`TransformFinalBlock` should be used in some other way, but unfortunately, MSDN docs don't explain much about these methods.
Any thoughts?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Plain text size is 504 bytes, 480 bytes are decoded and 504-480 = 24 bytes are remaining. These 24 bytes should be returned by TransformFinalBlock.
On the other hand, 56-byte doesn't fit into 32-byte cipher block.

Comment: Interesting.  Bear in mind that with PaddingMode.PKCS7, your 504 byte starting size is no longer going to apply.  To encrypt the plaintext, the cipher will pad it out to 512 bytes.  This would be true with the 32 byte block size or the more commonly used 16 byte block size.  I am still contemplating the TransformFinalBlock behavior though.

Comment: So when the while loop is reading the ciphertext back in, buffer gets the last 32 bytes (480 - 512 when we consider the padding), but the while condition then fails, so decPos is not incremented there.  I still cannot get how TransformFinalBlock is yielding 56 bytes though.  I would have expected tailBytes to be 32 at that point, and then you would strip the padding.  Normally all of this is done invisible to the programmer because you just use CryptoStream, but it is an interesting puzzle.

Comment: @WDS 

> but the while condition then fails, so decPos is not incremented there
<br>
Just as intended: last `Read()` puts last block into `buf` and after the second condition failure execution proceeds on `TransformFinalBlock` below.

Comment: Ah, got you.  I hope I don't sound stupid asking this, but have you confirmed that tailBytes is 56 bytes or have you only concluded that it is?  That is the part that really stumps me, that TransformFinalBlock is returning this size of a byte array.  I would have expected it to return 32 bytes or if not 32, then 64 (possibly because of transforming the last block twice or something).  Have you looked at the contents of the tailBytes array?  That may give a clue what is happening, unless it is all 'z' bytes

Comment: @WDS `TransformFinalBlock` should encode/decode last block and add/remove padding bytes. That is the reason why it returns new buffer and, unlike `TransformBlock`, does not accept destination buffer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88953/discussion-between-nitrocaster-and-wds).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am being silly.  Indeed that is one of the main purposes of TFB, so that it can remove padding.  And per the MSDN documentation (lacking though that documentation is) the thing has to return a byte array (instead of using a specified destination in the arguments) because it is unknown how large it will be until the transformation is done and padding removed.  I will try this on my computer and post again in a bit.

Comment: I have run some tests of my own on your code.  The problem appears not to be with the TFB.  If you change your 504 'z' bytes into a pattern of bytes like "abcdef..." then it is easier to spot the issue.  The first block is being transformed twice.  After that everything is offset 32 elements in the array from where it should be until you reach the end and get an out of bounds exception.  I am stumped exactly *why* the first block is being transformed twice, but you should look for the error there, not in TFB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the thing:
When `TransformBlock` is called first time, it copies the last block of the input buffer to the so called *depad buffer* and then transforms and writes remaining blocks to the output buffer. During next calls it transforms data from depad buffer, writes it to the output buffer, copies the last block of the input buffer to the depad buffer again, and writes transformed remaining blocks to the output, just as the first time.

**TL;DR:** `TransformBlock` caches the last block of input data so when `TransformFinalBlock` is called, it can grab the last block and remove padding. Without caching, the last block may be handled by `TransformBlock`. In that case, padding wouldn't be removed.